# Getting characters count in a string SQL

Tags: sql

Getting count in below format using SQL 'aaabbcdFFFFGGH' AS

```
A   3
B   2
C   1
D   1
F   4
G   2
H   1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: You need to tag your question with the database you are using.  Further, you should realize that this is not a natural operation for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Original_String VARCHAR(50);
declare @searchstring varchar(10);
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE (Characters VARCHAR(5),COUNTS INT)
SET @Original_String='aaabbcdFFFFGGH'

DECLARE @i int=65
WHILE @i < 91
BEGIN

set @searchstring = CHAR(@i)

IF len(@original_string) - len(replace(@original_string, @searchstring, ''))<>0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES(@searchstring,len(@original_string) - len(replace(@original_string, @searchstring, '')))
 END
SET @i=@i+1;
END

SELECT * FROM @RESULT
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS, so here is a solution for Postgres:

```
select upper(w), count(*)
from regexp_split_to_table('aaabbcdFFFFGGH','') as t(w)
group by upper(w)
order by upper(w);
```

Answer (score 0):

If by chance SQL Server

**Example**

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = 'aaabbcdFFFFGGH'

Select CharVal = Substring(@String,N,1)
      ,CharCnt = count(*)
 From  (Select Top (len(@String)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values N1,master..spt_values N2 ) N
 Group By Substring(@String,N,1)
```

**Returns**

```
CharVal CharCnt
a       3
b       2
c       1
d       1
F       4
G       2
H       1
```